# Set table view cell height by identifier - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, height, row

I am trying to set the height of each cell in the table view depending on the identifier. I do not want to use indexPath.row, because the i am filling the cell from an array containing a flag for each type of cell and the order is random. Exactly 3 types of cells.

I used this code but it causing an error:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    let cell = tableV.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    if(cell?.reuseIdentifier == "homeFeaturedR"){
        return 200
    }else{
       return 360
    }
}
```

The error is at this line:

```
let cell = tableV.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can use flag of datasource array to return cell height!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `heightForRowAt` method is called before `cellForRowAt`. This means that by the time `heightForRowAt` is called, the cell at that index path is not yet created. Therefore, you can't access its `reuseIdentifier` or anything like that.

This means that instead of trying to figure out what height to return by looking at the cell, you should try to figure out the height using your model.

Dynamic table views ought to have a datasource/model. Your table view should have one as well. Look at your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, under what conditions do you dequeue a cell with the identifier `homeFeatureR`? It is most likely an if statement checking something:

```
if someCondition {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "homeFeatureR")!
    // set properties
    return cell
}
```

Now, you can just check if `someCondition` is true, if it is true, that means the cell's identifier must be "homeFeatureR", which means you should return 200.

```
if someCondition {
    return 200
} else {
    return 360
}
```

Answer (score 1):

talking about UITableView lifecycle

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
```

it's called before

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

hence I guess your

```
func cellForRow(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell?
```

returns nil

Answer (score 0):

Seem like you wrong when select the `tableView`. You using the `tableV` not a `tableView` inside the function `heightForRowAt indexPath`. Let's change that and try again even this isn't a best ways in my mind.

Answer (score -1):

First duque cell

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
```

after that set cell height as you like.